# readfile won't work with pickmonkey and pixlr

Tags: php, readfile

I am using two image editing tools. 1: pickMonkey 2: Pixlr.
There two senarios where i am using these tools to edit images.

Scenario 1: If condition one is true i user header("Location:filepath");
Scenario 2: If condition is false i am using readfile();

Images can be loaded to the tool and works out all fine. But the second scenario doesn't work. The reason for using readfile is related to the system architect. I don't want to use url header as i have rewrite rules which i am trying to avoid. The explaination for using readfile is irrelevant but its for those who wonder why am i using two approaches, just trying to clearify my point.

Anyone can tell me why is it so? how can i solve this problem